# Pixel color slightly changed after PyTorch, OpenCV and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch

I've been trying to run a pre-trained model which uses PyTorch, NumPy and OpenCV to upscale pixelated images. Problem is, after I save the image, it looks the same but when I insert them on the spriting software, it detects some color differences on the background.

I've tried changing the background color to something like Magenta, since I'm working with BMP and no image will have that color, but after running on the neural network I get some differences in pixels values. The magenta still looks like magenta, but the pixel values are not the same.

I've also tried calculating if the new color is close to magenta so I could replace it with the original background but no luck as well, I got pretty close to be honest, but the pixels right next to the subject were still in the old color.

Am I doing something wrong or do you have any suggestions?

Here's the code

```
import sys
import os.path
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import architecture as arch

model_path = 'models/model.pth'  # models/RRDB_ESRGAN_x4.pth OR models/RRDB_PSNR_x4.pth
device = torch.device('cuda')  # if you want to run on CPU, change 'cuda' -> cpu
# device = torch.device('cpu')

test_img_folder = 'LR/*'

model = arch.RRDB_Net(3, 3, 64, 23, gc=32, upscale=4, norm_type=None, act_type='leakyrelu', \
                        mode='CNA', res_scale=1, upsample_mode='upconv')
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path), strict=True)
model.eval()
for k, v in model.named_parameters():
    v.requires_grad = False
model = model.to(device)

print('Model path {:s}. \nTesting...'.format(model_path))

idx = 0
for path in glob.glob(test_img_folder):
    idx += 1
    base = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    print(idx, base)

    original_background = [209, 237, 212]
    magenta = [255,0,255]

    # read image
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img[np.where((img == original_background).all(axis=2))] = magenta
    img = img * 1.0 / 255
    img = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(img[:, :, [2, 1, 0]], (2, 0, 1))).float()
    img_LR = img.unsqueeze(0)
    img_LR = img_LR.to(device)

    output = model(img_LR).data.squeeze().float().cpu().clamp_(0, 1).numpy()
    output = np.transpose(output[[2, 1, 0], :, :], (1, 2, 0))
    output = (output * 255).round()

    cv2.imwrite('results/{:s}.png'.format(base), output)
```

And here's the images, pre-processing and post

[image: PRE]
[image: POST]

The image pre-processing:

```
[[[255   0 255]
  [255   0 255]
  [255   0 255]
  ...
  [255   0 255]
  [255   0 255]
  [255   0 255]]
```

And post-processing:

```
[[[176.  73. 220.]
  [228.  62. 252.]
  [255.  45. 244.]
  ...
  [255.  34. 255.]
  [255.  58. 252.]
  [219. 100. 204.]]
```

Comment: I suspect you specified background color as BGR and the processing wanted it as RGB (or vice-versa)

Comment: Does it makes sense even if BGR or RGB Magenta are the same? I'm suspecting the difference could be caused by the model itself. Gonna try all other models I have and update

Comment: But original_background = [209, 237, 212] might be in the wrong order. By the way, which image is the orginal -- the smaller or the larger. The images posted look correct, if you want to change the background from blue-green to magenta

Comment: I guess it's in the correct order because the replacement went well! You know what I mean? The blue became magenta. The original is the smaller

Comment: If the blue became magenta, then the processing worked. So I do not understand what your issue is!

Comment: The magenta color on the displayed PNG has slight variations in the RGB channel values from pure magenta. That looks like there has been some JPG compression or some other color space changes back and forth that may not have been done to a high enough precision. What processing does Torch do to your images? When you resize an image, it is possible that it has some color changes depending upon how the resize is done. But it flat color areas, I would not expect that to happen normally, if done correctly.

Comment: I mean, it looks like magenta for a naked eye, but the pixels aren't (255,0,255) sorry about the confusion. I've tried each of my other models and for each one of them the final "magenta" is different, so I'm guessing I need to fix the resulting image instead

Comment: Looks to me like a precision issue somewhere. Have you tried convert your img to float before multiplying by 1.0/255. And at the end, rather than round, use np.clip(0.255).astype(np.uint8) to return to 8-bit values.

Comment: At the end you mean this? `np.clip(output, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Yes, that should work as `output = np.clip(output, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`  or `output = output.np.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Had to go with the first one because `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'np'` and the image is now all black xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214626/discussion-between-fmw42-and-danilo-lemes).